# Can we migrate all the data between on property to another of the same account in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created a google analytics account for my website. Because it also has an app, I have created 2 properties:

1. Universal GA,
2. GA4(web and apps)

First, I created the GA4 property and created a website stream. But now, I changed my strategy and thought of measuring all the app data from GA4 and website data from the universal GA.

Now, I want to migrate all the GA4 data(website stream data) to the universal property. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried looking around the web but did not came across any suitable steps. Please help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to migrate data from one property to another property.

Comment: can you give the source?

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics and Google Analytics 4 are two different systems based on a different data model, the two properties are distinct. However, you cannot migrate data from one property to another even in the case of two Universal Analytics properties, especially if they are one Universal and the other GA4.

Comment: is it possible if the source property is GA4 as well?

Comment: No, it is not possibile.

Comment: how about export the data then import it manually?

Comment: What data are you thinking of import manually and how?

Comment: I mean you export the data from the old property, then import it to the new property. Do you mean that GA doesn't allow us to export data?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I haven't. I thought this wasn't inconvenient for you for a quick reply, while with the info I can jump right to the action if it's possible, or another action if it's not possible. I thought that asking isn't a lost for you but will be a relief for me. If that's a problem then I'm sorry for not trying first

Comment: Actually I already answered you, it can't be done. The data import is only for some information, you can't import data like what you normally see, because you should be able to import raw data, and you can't.
I asked you if you tried, to understand if you had noticed something different from what I wrote, since I had already given you the answer a few comments ago. If you had seen something particular we can talk about it, otherwise if you haven't tried to do something that could justify questioning the impossibility (and that would be very strange), I haven't different response.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot migrate your data from universal analytics to GA4. Just you can do that you can define your new events and tags in GTM and connect your website to GA4. In this scenario your previous data will be in universal and new data will start from GA4.